# Button not moving when click on it using some calculation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When clicking on the button, I am assigning random margins from the top and left to it, so it can move but it's not working.

HTML

```
<button id="bouncing" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
```

JS

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var changeTop = (Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $("button").height()));
  var changeLeft = (Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $("button").width()));
  $("button").css("margin-top", changeTop + "px");
  $("button").css("margin-left", changeLeft + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine.You probably didn't include jQuery in your code

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var changeTop = (Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $("button").height()));
  var changeLeft = (Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $("button").width()));
  $("button").css("margin-top", changeTop + "px");
  $("button").css("margin-left", changeLeft + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bouncing" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add jquery. Add it via CDN or install it and it will work, like this-

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var changeTop = (Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $("button").height()));
  var changeLeft = (Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $("button").width()));
  $("button").css("margin-top", changeTop + "px");
  $("button").css("margin-left", changeLeft + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bouncing" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
```